says cannot specify system specification I tried driver size
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

//1
std::string formatFileSize(uintmax_t size) {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    if (size >= 1024 * 1024 * 1024) {
        oss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << (size / (1024.0 * 1024.0 * 1024.0)) << " GB";
    }
    else if (size >= 1024 * 1024) {
        oss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << (size / (1024.0 * 1024.0)) << " MB";
    }
    else if (size >= 1024) {
        oss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << (size / 1024.0) << " KB";
    }
    else {
        oss << size << " Bytes";
    }
    return oss.str();
}

2// 
std::string getFileType(const std::string& extension) {
    if (extension == ".txt") return "Text File";
    if (extension == ".jpg" || extension == ".jpeg" || extension == ".png") return "Image File";
    if (extension == ".mp4" || extension == ".avi") return "Video File";
    if (extension == ".mp3") return "Audio File";
    if (extension == ".cpp" || extension == ".h") return "C++ Source File";
    return "Unknown File Type";
}

3//  
std::string formatLastModifiedTime(const fs::file_time_type& ftime) {
    auto sctp = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::system_clock::duration>(
        ftime - fs::file_time_type::clock::now() + std::chrono::system_clock::now());
    std::time_t cftime = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(sctp);
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << std::put_time(std::localtime(&cftime), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
    return oss.str();
}

// 
void analyzeDiskUsage
(const std::string& rootDirectory) {
    try {
        fs::path rootPath(rootDirectory);
        if (fs::exists(rootPath) && fs::is_directory(rootPath)) {
            std::cout << "Disk Usage Analysis for: " << rootDirectory << std::endl;
            std::cout << "----------------------------------------" << std::endl;

            for (const auto& entry : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(rootPath)) {
                if (fs::is_regular_file(entry.path())) {
                    uintmax_t fileSize = fs::file_size(entry.path());
                    std::string fileName = entry.path().filename().string();
                    std::string fileExtension = entry.path().extension().string();
                    std::string formattedFileSize = formatFileSize(fileSize);
                    std::string lastModifiedDate = formatLastModifiedTime(fs::last_write_time(entry.path()));
                    std::string fileType = getFileType(fileExtension);

                    std::cout << "File: " << fileName << std::endl;
                    std::cout << "  Extension: " << fileExtension << std::endl;
                    std::cout << "  Size: " << formattedFileSize << std::endl;
                    std::cout << "  Last Modified: " << lastModifiedDate << std::endl;
                    std::cout << "  File Type: " << fileType << std::endl;
                    std::cout << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            std::cerr << "Error: Invalid directory path: " << rootDirectory << std::endl;
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex) {
        std::cerr << "An error occurred: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

5 
std::vector<std::string> listDrives() {
    std::vector<std::string> drives;
    for (char drive = 'A'; drive <= 'Z'; ++drive) {
        std::string drivePath = std::string(1, drive) + ":\\";
        if (fs::exists(drivePath)) {
            drives.push_back(drivePath);
        }
    }
    return drives;
}

//  
std::string selectDrive() {
    std::vector<std::string> drives = listDrives();
    if (drives.empty()) {
        std::cerr << "No drives found!" << std::endl;
        return "";
    }

    std::cout << "Available Drives:" << std::endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < drives.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << i + 1 << ". " << drives[i] << std::endl;
    }

    int choice;
    std::cout << "Select a drive (1-" << drives.size() << "): ";
    std::cin >> choice;

    if (choice < 1 || choice > drives.size()) {
        std::cerr << "Invalid choice!" << std::endl;
        return "";
    }

    return drives[choice - 1];
}

// Main fonksiyonu
int main() {
    std::string selectedDrive = selectDrive();
    if (!selectedDrive.empty()) {
        analyzeDiskUsage(selectedDrive);
    }
    return 0;
}

1=// 
Function for formatting file media
2=
Determining type from file extension
3=Function that analyzes the index
4=
5
=List available drivers on the computer

I tried using C++ to do disk analysis, but the error on my computer says that the system cannot find the specified file, but the language is C++20 standard and starts with a command file. I wrote the .cpp file in it, also I included my libraries. so this ones I add it.
Newnote:when  program started its came

What is the actual error? Is it a compiler error? A linker error? An error from your program when running? An error from the OS when running? Please [edit] your question to tell us. And copy-paste the error as text into the question.

"I tried using C++ to do disk analysis, but the error on my computer says that the system cannot find the specified file, but the language is C++20 standard and starts with a command file. I wrote the .cpp file in it,also i included my libraries. so this ones i add it" - Huh? That block of text makes no sense to me. Could you please try to clarify?

Does the tagged [tag:visual-studio-2010] support C++20?

Note that the type of 1024 * 1024 * 1024 and 1024 * 1024 is int. Those values can overflow, depending on the actual size of int.

2// -- 5 std::vector<std::string> listDrives() -- This could never had been in your real code.  The second thing is this: // Kullanıcının bir sürücü seçmesini sağlama -- please try and post code without comments, or if using comments, the comments should be in English.  If those comments convey important information to the volunteers here, then note that this section of StackOverflow is English-based, and the comment will make little to no sense to someone who does not know the language you are writing your comment in.

well i did what you are saying not visual studio and listdrivers yes its work someway not in this code its background
